# Python doesn't recognize ROS msg file in project structure

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ros

I am using ROS-melodic with the following environment variables:

```
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/florian/git/software_integration/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

For a project I want to get a obstacle detection and implement trajectory prediction using a LIDAR sensor. To achieve this, I installed the following github repo according to the given instructions:
https://github.com/kostaskonkk/datmo

The repo works so far, I can start the examples and the topics are published. Now I want to implement a new listener, with the following MWE:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from datmo.msg import TrackArray

def callbackTrackArray(data):
    print(type(data.date))

def getInput():
    rospy.init_node('obstacleComputer', anonymous= True)    
    tracks = rospy.Subscriber("datmo/box_kf", TrackArray, callbackTrackArray)
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    getInput()
```

But if I run it, it yells "No module named 'datmo'". But PyCharm even suggests me "datmo" if I type "import da", so he knows it.
I am using a Python 3.8 venv in PyCharm with the following Interpreter Paths:

[image]

Also, my project structure looks like this (and there the datmo package is located):
[image]

Full Error Stack:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/florian/git/software_integration/src/trajectory_prediction/src/ObstacleComputer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from datmo.msg import TrackArray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datmo'
```

Comment: Did you sourced your workspace, the code of ```datmo```is in?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the interpreter settings --> environment variables